# How can I run my Python script once every day starting from 1am, on Replit to prevent the keep_alive function from running my code every 5 mins

Tags: python, replit

```
import time
from keep_alive import keep_alive

def do_job():
   print("Get information from site once everyday starting from 1am")

keep_alive()

while True:
  do_job()
  time.sleep(86400)
```

> I'm running this code which is just the simplified version of my selenium task where the do_job() function contains the task.
> The issue I'm facing is that the keep_alive() server gets pinged every 5 mins and that immediately start the python script from the beginning again ignoring the time. sleep.
> How can I make this code run once a day at 1 am ignoring the keep_alive() pinging which is just to keep my server on while am offline.

Comment: maybe try cron jobs or another scheduler like apache airflow

Comment: https://replit.com/talk/ask/schedule-run-of-repl/9091 and https://replit.com/talk/ask/How-to-make-a-Python-program-run-once-every-day-without-the-Hacker-plan/143207

Comment: Replit (free) is not super reliable though. Python also has some popular sheduler modules, which could kick in incase there is a (successfull) restart